# Append line-break to tweet using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter

I downloaded this [jquery plugin](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) in order to show my tweets on my website. However, I need to add a line break between each tweet as they are currently too close together. Please can you tell me how I can do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
  $("#twitter").tweet({
    username: "so",
    avatar_size: 0,
    count: 2,
    loading_text: "loading tweets..."
  });
});

</script>

<div id="twitter" style="color: white;">
</div>
```

Comment: I would use CSS to handle the spacing (and keep the design and structure separate).  What does your CSS layout currently look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if the tweets are added in an unordered list, so you can do it in css:

```
#twitter li { margin-bottom: 15px; }
```